# Laravel, update method not working properly when i want to update image file, img become null

Tags: php, laravel, crud

i want to update forums table that contains

- fr_user_id
- fr_author
- fr_title
- fr_body
- fr_filename

code in my controller :

```
$request->validate([
            'fr_user_id' => 'required',
            'fr_author' => 'required',
            'fr_title' => 'required',
            'fr_body' => 'required'
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        if ($image = $request->file('fr_filename')){
            $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
            $imgName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($destinationPath, $imgName);
            $input['fr_filename'] = "$imgName";
        } else {
            unset($input['fr_filename']);
        }


        $forum = Forum::find($id);
        $forum->update($input);
        
        return redirect('/user/myforum')->with('success','Update Successfull');
```

my Routes

```
Route::match(['put','patch'],'/forum/update/{id}',[ForumController::class,'update'])->name('forum/update');
```

this code is working but the 'fr_filename' data is become null in my db, what should i do?

Comment: please share us `<form>` codes. does the form have `enctype='multipart/form-data'`?

Comment: @MuammerTop yes it has sir

Answer (score 0):

Had you checked, file is coming in request?

Comment: i checked it with dd($request) its there

`+request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#324 ▼
    #parameters: array:7 [▼
      "_token" => "CUqiI0xe6ChbpYnCGlvBwcdPFqQ21kdVMKJBjUvM"
      "_method" => "PUT"
      "fr_user_id" => "2"
      "fr_author" => "dummy_user1"
      "fr_title" => "tiga"
      "fr_filename" => "bukber2.jpg"
      "fr_body" => "tiga"
    ]
  }`